# Why does my *vc-log* buffer start with "Summary:" in Emacs 24.4?

Tags: version-control, emacs24.4

I just upgraded to Emacs 24.4 (from 24.3).  Now, whenever I run `vc-next-action` on a modified file, the `*vc-log*` buffer that comes up starts with the word "Summary:" in `log-edit-header` face, followed by a line of inverse video.

This wasn't happening in 24.3, but I can't find anything about it in NEWS.  What's going on?  I see this in both Git and Subversion working copies.

Answer (score 5):

Since around Emacs-24, the *vc-log* buffer supports/expects an RFC822-style format, with some headers handled specially (e.g. `Author:`, `Fixes:`, and `Summary:`).  In Emacs-24.4, the default message content was changed to make this more clear.

Comment: Can you expand on what the `Summary:` header does?

Comment: It should contain the summary of the change.  It's the line that will appear for example in short log output (one line per change).

Comment: To be clear, the 'Summary:' is included in the log message that's sent to the version control system.  Personally, I am already using the convention that the first line of the log message is the summary, so I don't want to cruft up every commit with this extra word :-(

Comment: No, "Summary:" is *not* included.

Comment: @Stefan it is for me, though... (using RCS if that makes any difference)

Comment: Then it's a bug.  Could you `M-x report-emacs-bug`?

Comment: I see the Summary: header included in the log message, using svn, so as you suggest I have filed http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=18954

Comment: The bug is now fixed in the emacs-25 branch, apparently.

Answer (score 3):

It's surprising that there is no way to configure this.  You can choose whether the Author: header should appear, but Summary: is jammed in by default no matter what.

I had to redefine a function:

```
(load "log-edit")
(defun log-edit-insert-message-template ()
  "Insert the default template."
  (interactive)
  (when (or (called-interactively-p 'interactive)
            (log-edit-empty-buffer-p))
    (when log-edit-setup-add-author
      (insert "\nAuthor: "))
    (message-position-point)))
```

Compared with the vanilla version in log-edit.el, I deleted the lines adding "Summary:" and "\n\n".

Loading `log-edit` first is needed (if you put the above code in your `.emacs`) because otherwise the new definition would be overwritten when that library is loaded the first time you do a commit operation.

Comment: In the bug reported above, http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=18954, a workaround is given. log-edit-insert-message-template is simply removed from log-edit-hook.